# Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've faced an issue when I'm trying to get the user input using `Scanner`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Insert a number: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Text1: ");
        String text1 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Text2: ");
        String text2 = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Insert a number: 55
Text1: Text2: Hi there!
```

As you can see, the program skipped `String text1 = input.nextLine();`. What is the problem here? and how to solve this issue?