# Switch Statement is making the first case skip a line

Tags: java, switch-statement

So I'm guessing that the solution to this is going to be really simple but I have no idea what I'm looking for so I'd like some help. What happens is that when I run the program, and choose case 1. It prints both "dog's name" and "dogs race" without giving me a chance to fill in the dogs name. So when I choose case 1 I start out only getting to fill in dogs race, how heavy, and how old it is!  here is the code I'm using...

```
do {
        System.out.println("(1 - reg\n2 - tail\n3- delete\n4-exit\nEnter number: ");

        // so this is where the switch stuff starts
        int option=sc.nextInt();
        switch (option) {



        case 1: System.out.println("Dog's Name: ");
            String na=sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Dog Race: ");
            String ra=sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("How heavy?");
            double wey=sc.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("How old?");
            double ag=sc.nextDouble();

            dog doggy= new dog(na, ra, wey, ag);
            kennel.add(doggy);
            break;

        case 2: System.out.println("its a tail");
            break;

        case 3: System.out.println("you delete");
            break;

        case 4: System.out.println("QUITTING\n(Data was not saved srry.)");
            play = false;


        default: System.out.println("try again");
            }
        }while(play);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextInt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextint)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to call `nextLine()` after your call to `nextInt()`, because that hasn't advanced the scanner to the next line yet.

Answer (score 1):

There's a newline reminder from your first sc.nextInt, you can change the delimiter to \n or just call nextLine(); just after reading the option (Using sc.useDelimiter("\n") )

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    `int option=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());`
This has both the effect of advancing the cursor to the next line and getting the typed number.