# Java input string

Tags: java

I'm having difficulties returning a user input string. If I have a code:

```
System.out.println("please enter a digit: ");
number1 = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("enter another digit: ");
number2 = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("enter a string: ");
string = in.nextLine();
//calculations

System.out.println(number1);
System.out.println(number2);
System.out.println(string);
```

it prints out the numbers but not the string. I feel like the solution is very simple but I'm having a brain fart right now. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need a in.nextLine() before calling in.nextLine() to read in the string. It is to consume the new line character from the previous line where you read integer.

Comment: @nhahtdh: you should post this as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextInt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextint)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call an extra `in.nextLine()` before calling `in.nextLine()` to read in the string. It is to consume the extra new line character.

As for explanation, let's use this input as example:

```
23[Enter]
43[Enter]
Somestring[Enter]
```

(23 and 43 can just be any number, the **important part is the new line**)

You need to call `in.nextLine()` to consume the new line from the previous `in.nextInt()`, particularly the new line character after `43` in the example above.

`nextInt()` will consume as many digits as possible and stop when the next character is a non-digit, so the new line is there. `nextLine()` will read everything until it encounters a new line. That's why you need an extra `nextLine()` to remove the new line after `43`, so that you can proceed to read the `Somestring` on the next line.

If, for example, your input is like this:

```
23 43 Somestring[Enter]
```

You don't press Enter and just continue to type, then your current code will show the string (which will be  `Somestring`, note the space) since there is no new line obstructing after `43`.

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
int number2 = in.nextInt();
```

passes a String to the statement

```
string = in.nextLine();
```

when you type the number and press ENTER. Consuming this string using `Scanner.nextLine()` before attempting to read another will fix the problem:

```
...
number2 = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
System.out.println("enter a string: ");
string = in.nextLine();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case `in.next()` would be sufficient to read the string if there is no space in between.

Answer (score 1):

String xxx;

Scanner number1 = new Scanner(System.in)

xxx = number1.nextLine();