# Scanner not letting to accept input for the last run of a loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextInt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextint)

Below is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            count++;
            sb.append(sc.nextLine());
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

I am not able to write the inputs for the last run of the loop, i.e., when `i==n-1`,although the variable `count` equals `n` at the end. Where is the error?

Comment: ***Related Question:*** [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextInt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextint)

Comment: thank you Eng. Fouad. Great help indeed.

Comment: Please post your test input, too. thx