# nextLine method in the Scanner

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextInt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextint)

Why is the empty `sc.nextLine();` under the husband so necessary? it did not equal to anything, and surely the wife did not have that line... but the program won't run without it. My book comments it as Skip over trailing newLine character. but I don't see how there's anything to skip!

```
public class FileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("For your blended family, \n enter the wife's name");
    String wife = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of her children:");
    int herkids = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the husband's name:");
    //sc.nextLine();  // Why is this line so necessary? 
    String husband = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of his children:");
    int hisKids = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println(wife + " and " + husband + " have " + (herkids + hisKids) + " children.");

    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnWatts ok, agreed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this question,

[Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextint)

Look at the accepted answer,

"The problem is with the input.nextInt() command it only reads the int value. So when you continue reading with input.nextLine() you receive the "\n" Enter key. So to skip this you have to add the input.nextLine(). Hope this should be clear now."

Comment: This should be closed as an exact duplicate

Comment: i see, does that mean the nextLine() command consumes the string and the \n ?

Comment: @user133466 From what I understand that would be correct.