# Scanner skipping input for first input on loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while, filewriter

I have a program to write to a text file, just using basic input from the scanner. I have it so it goes through the questions then a yes no to add another input. When the user(or tester being me) inputs y to do it again, it asks the 2 top questions at the same time so it does not get the input for the first question, any reason why this is happening? Here is an example 
    Would you like to create another entry? Y/N
    y
    What is the course code for the assignemnt?
    What is the name of the assignment?

```
do{
    System.out.println("What is the course code for the assignemnt?")
    course = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the name of the assignment?");
    gName = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What did you get on the assignment?");
    yourGrade = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What was the assignment out of?");
    gMax = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What was the assignment weighted?");
    gWeight = s.nextLine();

    pw.printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s",course, gName, yourGrade, gMax, gWeight);
    pw.println("");
    System.out.println("Would you like to create another entry? Y/N");
    YN = s.next().charAt(0);
}
while(YN == 'Y' || YN == 'y');
    pw.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the output for a clearer view?

Comment: Just did as you commented lol.

Comment: I believe it's a duplicate of

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867589/nextline-method-in-the-scanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`YN = s.next().charAt(0);` won't comsume the end-of-line character which will get consumed by the next `nextLine` (that is on the next iteration), so you need to to another `nextLine` after it. Or read a line with `nextLine` and use `charAt(0)` on that like this: `YN = s.nextLine().charAt(0);`

Comment: @Kalkrin Meant nextLine. My bad. Was thinking in another language.

Answer (score 1):

Use `YN = s.nextLine().charAt(0);` instead of `YN = s.next().charAt(0);`

Answer (score 1):

change `YN = s.next().charAt(0);` to `YN = s.nextLine().charAt(0);`
I changed this here and it worked for me,