# Java: using hasNextInt with do-while loop, it ignores integer inputs at even times

Tags: java, list, addition, java.util.scanner, do-while

I am trying to learn Java programming by myself and came across the course CS106A provided by Stanford. It's a great free online course. I watched several of the [lecture videos](http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC84A56BC7F4A1F852) and I enjoyed them so far. I am now trying to do the assignments and I have this problem I can't solve by myself.

It is the number 5 of [this assignment](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icspmcs106a/13-assignment-2-simple-java.pdf). Basically, it requires the learner to create a console program to get some integers input by the user and in response, showing the biggest and smallest number.

The following code is what I have done and the problem is when I try to input integers, it will skip the even number of inputs. For instance if I enter 3,12,6,15,9 to the console, it will only get 3,6,9 , ignoring 12,15.

What did I do wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ass2_5MaxMinNumbers {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner;

        System.out.println ("This programme finds the largest and smallest numbers.");
        System.out.println ("After finished entering, enter \"End\" (without double quotes) to show the results.");

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int max = 0, min = 0;

        do {
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                int x = scanner.nextInt();
                list.add(x);
                System.out.println("user input: " + x);
            } else if(!scanner.hasNext("End")){
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer!");
            }
        } while (!scanner.hasNext("End"));

        max = list.get(0);
        min = list.get(0);
        for(int x = 1; x < list.size(); x++){
            if(list.get(x) > max){
                max = list.get(x);
            } else if(list.get(x) < min){
                min = list.get(x);
            }
        }

        System.out.println ("Smallest number: " + min);
        System.out.println ("Biggest number: " + max);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextInt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Scanner.nextInt` method only reads the next token from the input passed from user. So, it ignores the `linefeed` that is at the end of each input. And that linefeed goes as input to the next call to `Scanner.nextInt`, and hence your input is ignored.

You can use a blank `Scanner.nextLine` after each call to `Scanner.nextInt` to consume the linefeed.

```
if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();  // Add a blank nextLine
    list.add(x);
    System.out.println("user input: " + x);
}
```

---

Or you can also use `scanner.nextLine()` only for reading `integers`, and convert the input to `integer` using `Integer.parseInt`.

```
if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    int x = 0;

    try {
         x = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    list.add(x);
    System.out.println("user input: " + x);
}
```

Actually, since you are using `scanner.hasNextInt` in your if, you don't really need that `try-catch` around your `Integer.parseInt`, so you can remove that.

---

**UPDATE : -**

I would replace your `do-while` with a `while` and just remove the `if-else` check from inside.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String input = scanner.nextLine();

    if (input.equals("End")) {
        break;
    } else {
        try {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(input);
            list.add(num);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter an Integer");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that's one quick response! Didn't expect this quick, thank you for that! :D

For the if-else, silly me, didn't notice that. :P

Comment: Unfortunately the solutions do not work with me. I am using Eclipse IDE, not sure if it would affect anything.

Comment: @PeteC... No using Eclipse would not affect anything. I think it should work. Let me see your code.

Comment: @PeteC... Its better to replace your `do-while` with a `while` to avoid doing multiple test. See my update. As you can see, it uses just `one scanner.hasNextLine()` as opposed to `4 scanner.hasNext***` in your do-while.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake in the code you posted is that you are creating a new Scanner object with ever iteration of your loop. Initialize the scanner before the loop and your code works:

```
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
      if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
            int x = scanner.nextInt();
            list.add(x);
            System.out.println("user input: " + x);
        }
        //and so on...
```

BTW - the max and min values can be calculated inside the while loop without first storing the  values in a List.

Thank you for calling this free on-line class to my attention.

Comment: That would indeed be better but he would still have the issue if he does not consume the `\n` after calling `nextInt()`.

Comment: @Thorn... I did that for some reason, but I can't remember that now.

The course is great for beginners like me. It explains a lot of concepts that other online tutorials don't have.

Comment: @Thorn... I have also revised my code to calculate the max/min values inside the loop. That's a good advise, makes the code less messy, thanks!