# JAVA: Using String in Do While for decision

Tags: java, do-while

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class MultipicationTable{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Initialising selection variable to 0 
        int selection = 0;
        int MultiValue = 0;
        int UserValue = 0;

        // Initializing the count for loop
        int i;


        // Initializing Random1 and Random2 to get random values
        int Random1;
        int Random2;


        // Creating new Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{

        // Menu to select type of multipication
        System.out.println("Please select your option");
        System.out.println("1: Random Multipication table");
        System.out.println("2: Give your own numbers");

        // Getting the input from the above menu
        selection = input.nextInt();

        switch (selection)
        {
            case 1:


                Random1 = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
                Random2 = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);

                Random1 = Random1/10;

                System.out.println("You Random Value to pultiply is " + Random1);


                System.out.println("How long do you want? 2 - 100 ");


                MultiValue = input.nextInt();


                for (i = 1; i <= MultiValue; i++ )
                {
                    System.out.println("Multipication of " + Random1 + " * " + i + " is: " + Random1 * i);
                }



            case 2:

                System.out.println("What is your Number? ");
                UserValue = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("How long do you want to multiply? ");
                MultiValue = input.nextInt();

                for (i = 1; i <= MultiValue; i++ )
                {
                    System.out.println("Multipication of " + UserValue + " * " + i + " is: " + UserValue * i);
                }



        }

        System.out.println("Would you like to exit? ");
        String Exit = input.nextLine();

        }while(Exit != 'y');    

    }



}
```

I think my error is on this part of the code.

```
    System.out.println("Would you like to exit? ");
    String Exit = input.nextLine();

}while(Exit != 'y');
```

I get an error like "Exit cannot be resolved". My aim is to loop until the user enters `y` in that question.

Comment: By convention, variables should be lowercase and you would need to invoke the .equals function to properly perform String comparisons.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the condition in a `while` or `do...while` loop is in the outer scope. This means that any variables declared within the block of the `do...while` are no longer in scope when the condition is checked. To solve this problem, you need to declare your `exit` variable outside of the `do...while` loop:

```
String Exit = null;

do {
    // do something
    Exit = input.nextLine();
} while (Exit != 'y');
```

However, this code will still fail to compile because `Exit` is declared as a `String` but you are comparing it with `'y'` which is a `char`. String literals are always surrounded by double-quotes, so `"y"` is a String.

Now changing the condition to `Exit != "y"` will compile, but it will not run as expected. You need to compare `String`s using the `equals()` method. This means that the condition should be `!Exit.equals("y")`. Placing this inside the `while` condition should fix the problems with your loop.

Alternatively, if you want to check for the word "yes" or variants, you can use `while(Exit.charAt(0) != 'y');`. This checks to see if the first character in `Exit` is a 'y' character.

Comment: Comment on last paragraph: what if the input is "Yikes! No way!"? :P

Comment: The code by @Code-Guru worked!... But there is no loop...It goes directly to Menu again without asking to me to quit. It does display if I want to exit but then it displays menu directly. It looks like Exit = input.nextLine(); was not executed properly.

Comment: add `System.out.println("Exit value: " + Exit);` after `Exit = input.nextLine();` to see what's the value of `Exit`. Maybe that will make it clear. By the way: It is no Syntaxrule but it is convention to start variables with a lower case letter. Only classes and constants (`final`) should start with an upper case letter. And tell us, what you've changed in your while condition.

Comment: @Doorknob That was someone else's addition. For a school assignment like this seems to be, it seems like a reasonable way to go. I probably wouldn't do it myself, though.

Comment: @user1947402 Please edit your question or start a new one with the changes you have made and explain what the current problem is. We will be glad to help.

Comment: @user1947402 *"It does display if I want to exit but then it displays menu directly."* This sounds like your calls to nextInt are orphaning a new line character. Basically you need to make an empty call to nextLine after calling nextInt and it should work then. Question that's similar to that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx

Answer (score 1):

`String Exit` has to be declared outside the loop

```
String Exit =null;
do {
//body
Exit= input.next(); // or input.nextLine();
} while(!Exit.equals("y"));
```

Edited as mentioned by Kartik :
Should use equals to compare strings. and == checks if both variables refer to same object.

Comment: The code by @Code-Guru worked!... But there is no loop...It goes directly to Menu again without asking to me to quit. It does display if I want to exit but then it displays menu directly. It looks like Exit = input.nextLine(); was not executed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is the scope of `Exit` as @Subin has covered.You might want to use `}while(!Exit.equals("y");` as well.

You can look at [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for the reason. Basically your `!=` will likely always be true since it compares objects and thus will decide that they are two different objects.

Answer (score 0):

/*This is easy code  using do-while loop*/

```
    String  option;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter your Choice : ");
        option=predator.next();
        switch (option) {
            case "add":
                System.out.println("Addition : " + (a + b));
                break;
            case "sub":
                System.out.println("Subtraction : " + (a - b));
                break;
            case "mult":
                System.out.println("Multiplication : " + (a * b));
                break;
            case "div":
                System.out.println("Division : " + (a / b));
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You have entered wrong keyword : "+option);
        }
    }
    while (!option.equals("Quit"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    System.out.println("Would you like to exit? ");
    String Exit = input.nextLine();

}while(!Exit.equals('y');
```

Comment: 1. Syntax error 2. Scope is local 3. Probably copied from Karthik's answer 4. downvoted