# Problems with Scanner.nextLine in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, system.in

In Java, I have tried

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Name is \"" + name + "\"");
    }
}
```

but it doesn't output `Name:` before asking for the input.

The console just shows an empty console window in which I can input the name.

How can I make sure `Name:` is outputted before asking for the name?

## Edit

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.print("Name: ");

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Name is \"" + name + "\"");

        System.out.print("Age: ");
        int age = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Age is " + age);

        System.out.print("Name: ");
    }
```

Comment: Didn't make any changes

Comment: You're right - flushing wasn't it. The `while( ..hasNextLine() )` is waiting for input, which is why it doesn't print..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your println **before** the while loop and then add one at the end.

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.print("Name: ");        
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Name is \"" + name + "\"");
        System.out.print("Name: ");
    }
}
```

The scanner waits until it receives input before it runs the next code so just put the print before the scanner and then at the end of the while loop.

Comment: But it's a loop, so I want to print the name every time the loop is run

Comment: It does, try to run it.

Comment: You can see that it prints before the scanner, and then once its been scanned it prints it again.

Comment: You should also explain why it didn't work properly for the OP originally... Basically, `Scanner#hasNextLine()` waits for some input if the stream is still open... So, it won't enter the loop until you input something...

Comment: Ah I see. But what about the code in my edit? It doesn't work behave correctly on second iteration

Comment: @Jamgreen What doesn't work on the second iteration?

Comment: @Jamgreen, see my edit for explanation to your edit :p

Answer (score 0):

You should put `System.out.print("Name: ");` before of the while loop like this:

```
  try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Name is \"" + name + "\"");
        }
    }
```

If you want to know the cause of this issue take a look at this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452613/issues-with-nextline)

Comment: If you have the same answer as me, you don't need to post another.

Comment: @10Replies I think that but where is the problem i answered without see your answer

Answer (score 0):

This might be a better design to avoid duplicated code. 
Don't have to restrict the loop end condition to the while statement ;)

```
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            if (!sc.hasNextLine()) break;
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Name is \"" + name + "\"");
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**:
Your edit does not work correctly because `sc.nextInt()` is not eating the line feed, so put `sc.nextLine()` after the `sc.nextInt()`.