# what is the problem with string printing with the help of the code

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d= scan.nextDouble();
        String s = scan.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Why I cannot print the string in the above code?

```
String: 
Double: 3.1415
Int: 42
```

Comment: You're possibly leaving a dangling new line character in the stream after `nextInt` and `nextDouble`

Comment: Before anybody can help you will need to show EXACTLY what you typed in, including all CR and newline characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issues with nextLine();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452613/issues-with-nextline)

Answer (score 2):

In the console when you are entering 42 and press enter, it takes 42 as int value and "enter"(or newline i.e /n) as string. But as there is no nextLine() after nextInt(), it avoids the newline. When you enter 3.1415 and press enter, it takes 3.1415 as double and enter/newline as string. 
So solution can be add another extra `nextLine()` after `nextDouble()`