# while inputting multi line input the last line only is considered

Tags: java

I'm trying to input some test cases at once to this program and it just keeps outputting the result for the last input only without the remaining inputs

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BeautifulStrings2 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //File f=new File("input.txt");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader in1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n=in.nextInt();
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            String s=in1.readLine();
            System.out.println(s);
            String chars="";
            if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0))){
                chars+=s.charAt(0);
            }
            else {
                chars+=Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));
            }
            for (int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
                boolean flag=true;
                for (int k=0;k<chars.length();k++){
                    if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(j))){
                        if (chars.charAt(k)==Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(j))){
                            flag=false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (flag){
                    chars+=Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(j));
                }
            }
            String temp=chars;
            chars="";
            for (int j=0;j<temp.length();j++){
                if (temp.charAt(j)>64&&temp.charAt(j)<91)
                    chars+=temp.charAt(j);
            }
            int [] numbers=new int[chars.length()];
            Arrays.fill(numbers, 0);
            for (int j=0;j<chars.length();j++){
                for (int k=0;k<s.length();k++){
                    if (chars.charAt(j)==Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(k))){
                        numbers[j]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            Arrays.sort(numbers);
            int factor=26,sum=0;
            for (int j=chars.length()-1;j>=0;j--){
                sum+=numbers[j]*factor;
                factor--;
            }
            System.out.println("Case #"+i+": "+sum);
        }
    }

}
```

sample input

```
5
ABbCcc
Good luck in the Facebook Hacker Cup this year!
Ignore punctuation, please :)
Sometimes test cases are hard to make up.
So I just go consult Professor Dalves
```

what the output should be

```
Case #1: 152
Case #2: 754
Case #3: 491
Case #4: 729
Case #5: 646
```

the actual output

```
Case #1: 646
```

EDIT ! 
Now I've edited my code to use only Scanner object and added in.nextLine() to skip the first line

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BeautifulStrings2 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //File f=new File("input.txt");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        //BufferedReader in1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n=in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            String s=in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(s);
            String chars="";
            if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0))){
                chars+=s.charAt(0);
            }
            else {
                chars+=Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));
            }
            for (int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
                boolean flag=true;
                for (int k=0;k<chars.length();k++){
                    if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(j))){
                        if (chars.charAt(k)==Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(j))){
                            flag=false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (flag){
                    chars+=Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(j));
                }
            }
            String temp=chars;
            chars="";
            for (int j=0;j<temp.length();j++){
                if (temp.charAt(j)>64&&temp.charAt(j)<91)
                    chars+=temp.charAt(j);
            }
            int [] numbers=new int[chars.length()];
            Arrays.fill(numbers, 0);
            for (int j=0;j<chars.length();j++){
                for (int k=0;k<s.length();k++){
                    if (chars.charAt(j)==Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(k))){
                        numbers[j]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(chars);
            Arrays.sort(numbers);
            int factor=26,sum=0;
            for (int j=chars.length()-1;j>=0;j--){
                sum+=numbers[j]*factor;
                factor--;
            }
            System.out.println("Case #"+i+": "+sum);
        }
    }

}
```

the output

```
Case #1: 152
Case #2: 754
Case #3: 491
Case #4: 729
```

and after I press enter the fifth line appear

```
Case #5: 646
```

how can I make it appear without having to press enter ?!

Comment: *Related Question*: [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextInt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextint)

Comment: I tried adding in.nextLine(); before the main loop .. still the same !!

Comment: Ok I removed the bufferedreader and kept the in.nextLine() before the main loop .. now it outputs 4 outputs and I still have to press enter for the fifth output to appear !!

Comment: If you've changed the code and now have a new problem, then you will want to post the *latest* code and edit your question. I'd leave your current code in place and add your new code to the bottom so as to not make our current answers look irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the standard input stream, System.in, **twice** in two different stream readers, one a Scanner, and the other a BufferedReader:

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
BufferedReader in1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

That looks to be a **very** dangerous thing to do and prone to error. Why not simply use the Scanner (or BufferedReader) for everything?

If you do use a Scanner for all, then yes, use `nextLine()` after `nextInt()` if the next token will be on the next line. If using the Scanner, you wouldn't even need the 5 number at the top of the file since you'd read lines until the scanner's `hasNextLine()` returns false.

Comment: used only scanner and now it makes a new problem .. check the edited code please :)