# Skipping An Input line in java

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, output

So I have an addItem() method where I can add a book, tape, or cd object to my inventory. To store the book, tape, or cd object, I obtain the title, author, and price of the object from the user. HOWEVER, when I run the program, it skips the "please enter the title: " and goes right to "please enter the author:". Then when I have it show the information, the title field is 'null'.

```
static void addItem(int type) {     

    String title;
    String author;
    Double price;

    System.out.println("Please enter the title");
    title = keyboard.nextLine()

    System.out.println("Please enter the author");
    author = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the price");
    price = keyboard.nextDouble();


        if(type == 0){
            Book BookStoreItem;

                BookStoreItem = new Book(title, author, price);

            System.out.println("You've entered:");
            System.out.println("Title: " + BookStoreItem.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Author: " + BookStoreItem.getAuthor());
            System.out.println("Price: " + BookStoreItem.getPrice());
        }

        if(type == 1){
            Tape BookStoreItem;

            BookStoreItem = new Tape(title, author, price);

            System.out.println("You've entered:");
            System.out.println("Title: " + BookStoreItem.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Author: " + BookStoreItem.getAuthor());
            System.out.println("Price: " + BookStoreItem.getPrice());
        }

        if(type == 2){                  
            CD BookStoreItem;

            BookStoreItem = new CD(title, author, price);

            System.out.println("You've entered:");
            System.out.println("Title: " + BookStoreItem.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Author: " + BookStoreItem.getAuthor());
            System.out.println("Price: " + BookStoreItem.getPrice());
        }


}//end of addItem()
```

Here is a sample output:

```
Press:
    0    To add a book to the inventory
    1    To add a tape to the inventory
    2    To add a Cd to the inventory
Please enter your choice: 0
Please enter the title:
Please enter the author: John Smith
Please enter the price: 55.50

Title: null
Author: John Smith
Price: 55.5
```

Here's an update with the menu on it:

```
static void printMenu() {
    System.out.println("\nPress:");
    System.out.println("\t" + ADD_BOOK + "\tTo add a book to the inventory\n");
    System.out.println("\t" + ADD_TAPE + "\tTo add a tape to the inventory\n");
    System.out.println("\t" + ADD_CD + "\tTo add a CD to the inventory\n");
    System.out.println("\t" + SHOW_ITEM_LIST + "\tTo display a list of available books\n");
    System.out.println("\t" + SEARCH_ITEM + "\tTo search for a specific book\n");
    System.out.println("\t" + QUIT + "\tTo exit\n");
}
```

and with the choices:

```
static void runBookStoreApplication() {
    int userChoice = QUIT;
    String quitMessage = "\nThank you for using the BookStoreApplication!";
    String invalidOptionMessage = "\nInvalid option!"; 

    do{
        printMenu();
        userChoice = getUserChoice();

        switch (userChoice) {
            case ADD_BOOK:
                addItem(0);
                break;
            case ADD_TAPE:
                addItem(1);
            case ADD_CD:
                addItem(2);
            case SHOW_ITEM_LIST:
                showItemList();
                break;
            case SEARCH_ITEM:
                searchItem();
                break;
            case QUIT:
                System.out.println(quitMessage);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(invalidOptionMessage);
        }
    } while(userChoice != QUIT);

}//end of runBookStoreApplication
```

with getUserChoice:

```
static int getUserChoice() {
    int choice;

    System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
    choice = keyboard.nextInt();

    return choice;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextInt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show us the code where you ask "Please enter your choice:", but I bet that you are using `keyboard.nextInt()` or something. This method does not consume all the line, just the integer `0`, so when you call `nextLine()` afterwards it actually returns immediately with the rest of the line (that is, with an empty string).

To solve this, call `keyboard.nextLine()` before your method.

#### Edit:

now that you have put your `getUserChoice()` method, you can see that there is a call to `keyboard.nextInt()`, as I presumed. Just call `nextLine()` after it so you consume all the line and the scanner is ready for your next input:

```
static int getUserChoice() {
    int choice;

    System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
    choice = keyboard.nextInt(); // consume just the integer

    // consume the rest of the line
    keyboard.nextLine();

    return choice;
}
```

Comment: Ok I updated the code. I didn't think i had nextInt() in there?

Comment: What is in  `getUserChoice()` ?

Comment: @user1368970 You have `nextDouble()`.

Comment: `nextDouble()` in the posted code is *after* the problematic code.

Comment: Ok I added getUserChoice().

Comment: Thanks, I have modified my answer accordingly.