# Scanner nextLine is being skipped

Tags: java

So this is the code I am using:

```
System.out.println("Create a name.");
name = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Create a password.");
password = input.nextLine();
```

But when it reaches this point it just says "Create a name." and "Create a password." both at the same time and then I have to type something. So it's basically skipping the Scanner parts where I need to type a String. After "Create a name." and "Create a password." is outprinted and I type then, both name and password are changing to what I typed in. How do I fix this?

This is the full class. I am just testing so it isn't actually going to be a program:

```
package just.testing;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestingJava
{
    static int age;
    static String name;
    static String password;
    static boolean makeid = true;
    static boolean id = true;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        makeid(null);
        if(makeid == true){
            System.out.println("Yay.");
        }else{

        }
    }
    public static void makeid(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Create your account.");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your age?");
        int age = input.nextInt();
        if(age<12){
            System.out.println("You are too young to make an account.");
            makeid = false;
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Create a name.");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Create a password.");
        password = input.nextLine();
        return;
    }
}
```

And sorry for my bad grammar. I am not English so it is kinda hard for me to explain this.

Comment: Have you properly declared and initialized the `Scanner`

Comment: Yes: "Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);"

Comment: You need to make sure that you initialize the Scanner with System.in.  Edit: ah, ok

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) ?

Comment: Cyrille. This is all I did in my Eclipse. I don't know how to make an example for it since this already is one. Basically when I run it it says:

Comment: Create a name.
Create a password.
<And then here I can type...>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The nextInt() ate the input number but not the EOLN:

```
Create your account.
What is your age?
123 <- Here's actually another '\n'
```

so the first call to nextLine() after create name accept that as an input.

```
System.out.println("Create a name.");
name = input.nextLine(); <- This just gives you "\n"
```

User Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()) or add another input.nextLine() after reading the number will solve this:

```
int age = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

or

```
int age = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine()
```

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx) for a duplicated question.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I still dunno why the Int is doing that, though...

Comment: You could check the question linked in my answer, it has a cleaner answer (I'm a horrible teacher, I learned that from experience).

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt actually tell you why the lines are being skipped, but as you're capturing names and passwords you could use Console:

```
Console console = System.console();
String name = console.readLine("Create a name.");
char[] password = console.readPassword("Create a password.");
System.out.println(name + ":" + new String(password));
```

Comment: Not working because I might want to use the Method again later and then the String password is already made...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use next() instead of nextLine(). I have tested it in eclipse. its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

`next()` will work but it will not read the string after space.