# Logical operator in loops for java

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, operators

Write a program that continuously prompts the user to enter integers from the keyboard. The program terminates when the integer entered is –5 or 0 or is greater than 8. Use logical ‘and’ in your loop control condition. Test your program carefully to ensure that all the loop termination criteria are met.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class ques {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int num;

    System.out.print("Enter n (-5 or 0 to stop):");
    do {
        num = input.nextInt();

        if ((num!=-5) && (num!=0) && (num>8)){
            System.out.println("Integers: "+num);
        }
    }while ((num!=-5) && (num!=0) && (num>8)); {
        System.out.println("Integers:" +num);
    }


}
```

}

Started out with this but couldn't complete it. Help.

Comment: What is wrong with the answer? It is poorly formatted and has redundant code. Is that your concern?

Comment: Where did u get stuck ?

Comment: You probably wanted `num<=8` in your condition instead of `>`?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have problems with `Scanner` you have to add an `input.nextLine()` without storing the value after `input.nextInt()`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ques {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int num;

    System.out.print("Enter n (-5 or 0 to stop):");
    do {
        num = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        if ((num!=-5) && (num!=0) && (num>8)){
            System.out.println("Integers: "+num);
        }
    }while ((num!=-5) && (num!=0) && (num<=8)); {
        System.out.println("Integers:" +num);
    }  
}
}
```

If you want to know why do you have to put `input.nextLine()` you can see this answer that I posted some months ago: [Why isn't the scanner input working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927425/why-isnt-the-scanner-input-working/30927515#30927515)

Also, in your while condition you have to put `num<=8` instead of `num>8`.

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: `input.nextLine()` is not required in this case.

Comment: num = input.nextInt(); does the same thing in this case

Comment: @Codebender But consider that, by error, it enter a `String`. It will crash. With this method you avoid it.

Comment: @Codebender Of course, if he just add numbers one by one without spaces it is not neccesary.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up the last condition, it should be `num<=8`, instead of `num > 8`.

Your loop should continue until one of these conditions are met:

- num == -5
- num == 0
- num > 8

This is equivalent to continue while:

- num != -5
- num != 0
- num <= 8

As you can see, the last expression in the condition you wrote is wrong, it should be `num <= 8`, instead of `num > 8`.

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement you are saying if the input number is not -5, not 0 or greater than 8.

This is your error:

Change `num>8` to `num<=8`

working code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ques 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int num;

        System.out.print("Enter n (-5 or 0 to stop):");
        do 
        {
            num = input.nextInt();

            if ((num!=-5) && (num!=0) && (num<=8))
            {
                System.out.println("Integers: "+num);
            }
        }while ((num!=-5) && (num!=0) && (num<=8)); 
        {
            System.out.println("Integers:" +num);
        }
    }
}
```