# Why cant I input info after if statement? No errors show

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How can I get the program to ask for input using the scanner after the if statement?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App1 {

    public static void main(String[] Args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String gender;
        String fName;
        String lName;
        int age;
        String female = "F";
        String male = "M";
        String a = "";
        String gettingMarried = "y";
        String notGettingMarried = "n";

        System.out.println("What is your gender (M or F)");
        gender = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your first name?");
        fName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your last name?");
        lName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Age:");
        age = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        if (gender.equals(female) && age >= 20) {
            System.out.println("Are you married " + fName + " (y or n?)");
            a = keyboard.nextLine();

        } else if (gender.equals(male) && age >= 20) {
            System.out.println("Are you married" + fName + "(y or n?)");
            a = keyboard.nextLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. It seems like you can simplify your if statement to age >= 20 but I might be missing something.
2. But more to the point of your question, is it printing the line: "Are you married .... "?

Comment: What would only happen if neither case is being satisfied.  For example if gender was lowercase 'm'/'f' or age was less than 20.

Comment: why dont you provide your input text?

Comment: Yes it prints Are you married

Comment: but doesnt ask for the input

Comment: What is your gender (M or F)
F
What is your first name?
Jerry
What is your last name?
Woods
Age:
24

Are you married Jerry (y or n?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you use a `nextInt()` that only takes the `int` value and not the full line. When you try again to read with `keyboard.nextLine()` what you are catching it's the rest of the sentence of the line in which you put the `int`.

Change the `System.out.println();` before your `if` statement to `keyboard.nextLine();`

**Edit:** If you want a more extended explanation about why you have to put `keyboard.nextLine();` after your `keyboard.nextInt()` you can consult my answer in another question with the same problem: [Why isn't the scanner input working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927425/why-isnt-the-scanner-input-working/30927515#30927515)

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: But the age is a the age which is a int. I get an error when I change it.

Comment: Oh no, you don't have to change it. You have to let, as you have, `age = keyboard.nextInt();`. You just have to change the line `System.out.println();` to `keyboard.nextLine()` without storing the value.

Comment: Thanks worked well, I'm just trying to figure out what "keyboard.nextLine();" does.

Comment: @JerryWoods Look my other answer (in the link of the question that I put above). If it doesn't clearify your doubts just ask to me ;)