# Unknown java netbeans error

Tags: java, netbeans

Why won't the program work? When I type '1' at the first question and then type in something at the second, a red text comes up: (The program is not done but it should work shouldn't it?)

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 0  at
>   java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)  at
>   javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:37) Java
>   Result: 1

Code:

```
package javaapplication2;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author John
 */
public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int charAt = 0;
        int[] karies = new int[99];
        char[] ko = new char[99];
        char[] firstchar = new char[99];

        System.out.println("Type \"1\" for encryption and \"2\" for decryption:");


        if (sc.nextInt() == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter the text you want to encrypt:");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter the text you want to decrypt:");
        }
        String krypt = sc.nextLine();
        int longd = (sc.nextLine()).length();

        while (charAt < longd) {
            firstchar[charAt] = krypt.charAt(charAt);
            karies[charAt] = ((int)firstchar[charAt]);
            ko[charAt] = (char)(karies[charAt] - 7);
            charAt++;
        }
        System.out.println(krypt.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, The problem is not with the Netbeans. `sc.nextLine()` is the culprit. After entering the choice when you press enter that carriage return is consumed by the `sc.nextLine()`, as `sc.nextInt()` will read only number, not the `\n` at the end. To solve this you can use an extra `sc.nextLine()`.

```
if (sc.nextInt() == 1){
System.out.println("Enter the text you want to encrypt:");
}else{
System.out.println("Enter the text you want to decrypt:");
}
sc.nextLine(); // Extra added
String krypt = sc.nextLine();
int longd = (sc.nextLine()).length();
```

For more details you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898617/scanner-nextline-is-being-skipped) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods) questions.

Comment: It's simple. When you enter the choice as either 1 or 2, that you have scanned from user using the `sc.nextInt()`, now after this you are pressing the enter to go to new line to enter the string that you are trying to store in `krypt`. Here, `sc.nextInt()` takes only number part not the enter(carriage return part - `\n`) Hope it's bit clear now.