# Weird file.nextLine() behavior

Tags: java, file-io

Okay, so I'm having this weird issue where I'm trying to get a File to give input into several classes. Here is the method, most of which is commented out. At the specified point, I'm needed a multi-word string put in. However, while .next() works, .nextLine() fails.

New to java, so sorry if this is obvious.

```
public void readWeeklyData (String fileName) 
{
  try{
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);

        _leagueName = fileReader.nextLine(); //Outputs String properly despite spaces
        _leagueID = fileReader.nextInt();
        _numTeams = fileReader.nextInt();
       _numWeek = fileReader.nextInt();

      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;

       // while(i < _numTeams)
       // {
            Team team = new Team();
            team.setTeamID(fileReader.nextInt());
            System.out.println(team.getTeamID()); //Outputs 1011 properly
            team.setTeamName(fileReader.nextLine()); //Outputs nothing, with or without the while loops in comments. Yet when changed to fileReader.next(), it gives the first word of the team name.
           // team.setGamesWon(fileReader.nextInt());
          //  team.setGamesLost(fileReader.nextInt());
          //  team.setRank(fileReader.nextInt());

          // while(j < 3)
          //  {
           //     Bowler bowler = new Bowler();
         //       bowler.setBowlerId(fileReader.nextInt());
           //     bowler.setFirstName(fileReader.nextLine());
           //     bowler.setLastName(fileReader.nextLine());
          //      bowler.setTotalGames(fileReader.nextInt());
           //     bowler.setTotalPins(fileReader.nextInt());

           //     team.setBowler(j, bowler);
           //     j++;
           // }   

           // j = 0;

          //  _teams[i] = team; 
          //  i++;
        //}

   }

   catch(IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found... ");
   }
}
```

The file (Ignore the extra enters, as they were only there for formatting. This is only 2 iterations of teams.):

```
Friday Night Strikers
27408
4
0
1001
Fantastic Four
0
0
0
10011
Johnny
Blake
0
0
10012
Donald
Duck
0
0
10013
Olive
Oil
0
0
10014
Daffy
Duck
0
0
1002
The Showboats
0
0
0
10021
Walter 
Brown
0
0
10022
Ty
Ellison
0
0
10023
Gregory
Larson
0
0
10024
Sharon
Neely
0
0
```

Comment: Friday Night Strikers
27408
4
0
1001
Fantastic Four
0
0
0
10011
Johnny
Blake
0
0
10012
Donald
Duck
0
0
10013
Olive
Oil
0
0
10014
Daffy
Duck
0
0
1002
The Showboats
0
0
0
10021
Walter 
Brown
0
0
10022
Ty
Ellison
0
0
10023
Gregory
Larson
0
0
10024
Sharon
Neely
0
0
1003
High Rollers
0
0
0
10031
Malcolm
Holmes
0
0
10032
Verna
Frank
0
0
10033
Samuel
Adams
0
0
10034
Betty
Crocker
0
0
1004
Blazing Bowlers
0
0
0
10041
Justin
Bates
0
0
10042
Hannah
Storm
0
0
10043
Fats
Domino
0
0
10044
Jimi
Hendrix
0
0

Comment: Uh... The enters didn't come out right. My bad. Should I upload the file elsewhere?

Comment: Yeah. Here you go. Best I could do, though.

Comment: @Xenorosth Why wouldn't you just format it as code or in pre tags?

Comment: ***Related Question:*** [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7056749/597657)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Scanner#nextInt` doesn't consume newline characters, the newline character immediately after `1001` will be passed though to the `nextLine` statement and your team name will appear empty.

You need consume this character before reading the next line. You can use:

```
fileReader.nextLine(); // consume newline
team.setTeamName(fileReader.nextLine());
```