# initialization problems?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that lets the user enter an unknown value of names and then output the longest name entered. This is my code so far. When i compile I have several errors and they are all the same "cannot find symbol". Do i need to initialize those variables if so where?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Name 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 
        longestName(kb); 
    } 
    public static void longestName(Scanner sc) 
    {

        String name=kb.nextLine();
        biggestName=name;
        System.out.println("Type -1 if you want to quit");
        int number=kb.nextInt();
        While (number !=-1); 
        { 
            String name1=kb.nextLine();
            if (name1.length() > biggestName)
            {
                biggestName=name1;
            }
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Type -1 to quit.");
            int number1=kb.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Longest name is "+biggestName);

    }
}
```

Thanks for the help guys fixed the errors, and some other changes and the program gives the correct output.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Name 
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 
        longestName(kb); 
    } 
    public static void longestName(Scanner kb) 
    {

        String biggestName;
        System.out.println("Enter the first name");
        String name=kb.nextLine();
        biggestName=name;
        System.out.println("Type -1 if you want to quit");
        int number=kb.nextInt();
        while (number !=-1) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Enter another name");
            Scanner kb1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name1=kb1.nextLine();
            int length1=biggestName.length();
            int length2=name1.length();
            if (length2 > length1)
            {
                biggestName=name1;
            }
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Type -1 to quit.");
            number=kb.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Longest name is "+biggestName);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few errors in your code. Without explaining every error in detail, here is an example of a modified version which works:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Name 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 
        longestName(kb); 
    } 
    public static void longestName(Scanner sc) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter name, or type '-1' if you want to quit");

        String name=sc.nextLine();
        String biggestName="";

        while (!name.equals("-1")) 
        { 
            if (name.length() > biggestName.length())
            {
                biggestName=name;
            }
            name=sc.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Longest name is "+biggestName);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You passed in your `Scanner` to `longestName`, but in `longestName`, you named the parameter `sc`.  Use `sc` instead of `kb` in `longestName`.

Use lowercase `while` instead of `While`; remove the semicolon following the `while`; a semicolon there means that *that* is the body, instead of the `{` `}` block below it.

I assume that at the bottom of the while loop, that you want to assign the next integer to `number`, not a new variable `number1` that immediately goes out of scope.

You didn't declare what `biggestName` is (or `name`).

Comment: He did at least define name (`String name = kb.nextLine()`)

Answer (score 0):

Two errors here :

```
While (number !=-1);
```

`While` should be `while`, and the `;` makes an infinite loop.

And another problem is that you don't change `number` in the loop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1-

```
public static void longestName(Scanner sc)
```

Either change the name of the scanner to `kb`, or change every `kb` within the method to `sc`.

2- See [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

3- Use `while` instead of `While`, and remove the `;`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the below problems in the code:

1. `longestName()` method should be using the reference name `sc` instead of `kb` (since `kb` is having scope only in `main` method)
2. The variable `biggestName` is not declared. It should be either declared as a class variable or a variable in `longestName()` method and should be of type `String`
3. It is not `While`, it is `while` with 'w' in smaller case
4. There should not be a semicolon after the while statement
5. At the end of the while loop, the number to be compared for the while loop is to be calculated and is currently assigned to wrong variable. `kb.nextInt()` should be assigned to variable `number` and not to `number1` since the variable `number1` is never read/used.
6. The `>` operator can not be applied for String types. In the line `if (name1.length() > biggestName)`, we are comparing `int` with `String` and will result in compilation error. The line should be modified as `if (name1.length() > biggestName.length())`
7. Method `nextInt()` will cause `InputMismatchException` to be thrown if you are providing an input which is not a number.

Now I feel I should have written a corrected code like Joe Elleson did. But hope this answer helps.