# Basic Calculator Error

Tags: java

So I am trying to test a basic calculator, but the program ends right after it asks for "adding, subtracting, multiplying or dividing" - it doesn't give the user a chance to type. help appreciated please :) thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lator {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        float num1;
        float num2;
        String choice;

        Scanner imput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("This is a calculator.");
        System.out.println("Enter your first number.");
        num1 = imput.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Enter your second number.");
        num2 = imput.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Would you like to add, subtract, divide, or multiply?");
        choice = imput.nextLine();

        if(choice.equals("Add")||choice.equals("+")||choice.equals("Addition")) {
        System.out.println("Number1 " + num1 + " + " + "number2" + num2 + "=" + (num1 + num2));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The word is `input`. Also, the error probably occurs because you entered new line characters after each `nextFloat` while typing.

Comment: @Sotiros - Java allows you choose your variables names. Please focus on answering the question. (Anyway, in English, imput is a perfectly good spelling variant of input.)

Comment: @SualehFatehi `imput` is not an English word.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Btw I know it's 'input' but in java i type 'imput' because that's how i typed it when i first started learning java so now that's just what i'm used to.

Comment: @GhettoMan Try to lose that habit. Use correct terminology.

Comment: @HenryHarris I can be any of his future employers.

Comment: Variable names do make a difference. They're a form of documentation. Considering that imput could be confused with impute, which has a different meaning than input, it's an unnecessarily confusing name. If you are the only one that will look at the code, then no biggy. But if others will ever maintain your code, write for them.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code. Comments in the code explain the answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Lator {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            float num1;
            float num2;
            String choice;

            Scanner imput = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("This is a calculator.");
            System.out.println("Enter your first number.");
            num1 = imput.nextFloat();

            System.out.println("Enter your second number.");
            num2 = imput.nextFloat();

            imput.nextLine(); //ADDED LINE

            System.out.println("Would you like to add, subtract, divide, or multiply?");
            choice = imput.nextLine();

            if(choice.equals("Add")||choice.equals("+")||choice.equals("Addition")) {
            System.out.println("Number1 " + num1 + " + " + "number2" + num2 + "=" + (num1 + num2));

            }
        }
    }
```

We added `imput.nextLine();` because `imput.nextFloat();` leaves a leftover new line character that we need to clear out before scanning for the user's selection.

It was putting this new line character as the selection when the user is supposed to enter "Add". Let me know how this works out for you. See a similar answer here, [Java For Loop Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416757/java-for-loop-issue/17416833#17416833)

-Henry

Comment: This also works, I prefer my example because it uses less code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
choice = imput.nextLine();
```

to:

```
choice = imput.next();
```

This stores what the user writes in the String 'choice'.

You can test it by adding this as the next line:

```
System.out.println(choice);
```

Edit: This will only get the next word.  As per comments, if you were to expand your application to handle input like Square Root or something like that, you would want to go to the next line first:

```
imput.nextLine();
System.out.println("Would you like to add, subtract, divide, or multiply?");
choice = imput.nextLine();
```

The reason for needing to go to the next line is that the Scanner 'imput' is still on the previous line, just after the second float entered by the user.

I think that the best option for your application is to use my first example though and use `imput.next();` because your application only uses one word inputs.  Using `imput.nextLine();` could possibly expand the possibility of input errors, because it gets the whole line.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. :) Why exactly would .nextLine(); not work though, I thought .nextLine(); would work for all strings? thanks again

Comment: @GhettoMan I changed my answer to reflect this question, Henry Harris' answer works in this manner.  It's up to you which one you use, depending on the needs of the application.

Comment: @Henry Harris I actually think using imput.next(); is a better idea for this application.  Right now, the application only needs one word.  Using only next() instead of nextLine() prevents possible errors from input.

Answer (score 0):

**Not Related to Question but just an observation  (unless this is a simplified version of course!)** i.e. I misread the question

The program will just end after your last `next..()` call as it computes what it needs to then exits as the program has finished.

Add something to 'pause' the execution of the program such as

```
 // After calculating
 System.out.println("Press any key to continue");
 imput.next();
 // continue with what you want.
```

Comment: ...what does this have to do with his question?

Comment: Good point, misread the question as "program exits after selecting which operation to do."

Answer (score 0):

you could use this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lator {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        float num1;
        float num2;
        String choice;

        Scanner imput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("This is a calculator.");
        System.out.println("Enter your first number.");
        num1 = imput.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Enter your second number.");
        num2 = imput.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Would you like to add, subtract, divide, or multiply?");
        choice = imput.next();

        if(choice.equals("Add")||choice.equals("+")||choice.equals("Addition")) {
        System.out.println("Number1 " + num1 + " + " + "number2 " + num2 + " = " + (num1 + num2));

        }
    }
}
```

Use `choice.equalsIgnoreCase("add")` instead of `choice.equals("Add")`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class Calculate
 {public static void main(String args[])
 {int a,b,choice;
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("enter numbers");
   a=sc.nextInt();
   b-sc.nextInt()
   System.out.print("1.add\n2.sub\n3.mul\n4.div\n5.mod");
    System.out.println("enter choice");
    choice=sc.nextInt();
 do
 {
switch(choice)
{case 1:System.out.println("result is" +(a+b));
     break;
case 2:System.out.println("result is" +(a-b));
     break;
case 3:System.out.println("result is" +(a*b));
     break;
case 4:if(a>b)
   { System.out.println("result is" +(a/b));
     break;}
  else { System.out.println("invalid");
   break;}
 case 5:System.out.println("result is" +(a%b));
     break;
   default: System.out.println("invalid");
   break;
        }
        }
      while(choice!=6);
       }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
 
 System.out.println("Hello user welcome to calculator");
 

 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 char sign;
 
do{
 System.out.println("Enter a sign + or - or * or /:");

  sign = sc.next().charAt(0);
 }
 while(sign != '+' && sign!='-' && sign != '*' && sign != '/');

 
 System.out.println("Enter first number :");
 
 double num1 = sc.nextDouble();
 
 System.out.println("Enter second number :");
 
 double num2 = sc.nextDouble();

 if(sign == '+'){
 
double result = num1 + num2;

System.out.printf("The addition of the two numbers is : %,f", result );



 }
 else if (sign == '-'){
 
double  result = num1 - num2;

 System.out.printf("The subtraction of the two numbers is : %,f", result );
 
 
 }
 else if (sign == '*'){
 
 double result = num1 * num2;
 
  System.out.printf("The multiplication of the two numbers is : %,f", result );
 
 
 }
 
  else if (sign == '/'){
 
 double result = num1 / num2;
 
  System.out.printf("The division of the two numbers is : %,f", result );
  }
  else
     
      System.out.println("Please enter a valid sign ");

 }
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).