# My program is terminated without scanning string

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When I execute my code my program is terminated without scanning the string.

```
double x, y;
    String s;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
    x = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter Number 2: ");
    y = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter Operater: x,+,/,-");
    s = scan.nextLine();
    if(s.equals("x"))
    {
        System.out.print(x * y);

    }
    else if(s.equals("+"))
    {
        System.out.print(x + y);

    }
    else if(s.equals("/"))
    {
        System.out.print(x / y);

    }
    else if(s.equals("-"))
    {
        System.out.print(x - y);

    }
    scan.close();
```

my program ends before `s = scan.nextline();`
How come it ends before?

Comment: Have you used `scan.next()`?

Comment: The bahaviour as same for `Scanner.nextDouble()` as for `Scanner.nextInt()`, as in above question.

Comment: Add one extra `scan.nextLine();` before `s = scan.nextLine();`.

Comment: yes using scan.next() works but how come scan.nextline() doesn't work as it also scans strings...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx

Comment: Can you show me a small picture of the code when being ran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End of line you leave in the buffer.
`next( )` reads a token from the buffer until the next white space, while `nextLine( )` reads up to `\n`

```
...
System.out.print("Enter Number 2: ");
y = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter Operater: x,+,/,-");
s = scan.next();
...

Enter Number: 1
Enter Number 2: 2
Enter Operater: x,+,/,--
-1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The user input, optimally, would look like this:

> -*CURSOR HERE*- num1 NEWLINE
>
> num2 NEWLINE
>
> operator NEWLINE

If you do several `nextDouble()` calls, the program will read one double first.

> num1 -*CURSOR HERE*- NEWLINE
>
> num2 NEWLINE
>
> operator NEWLINE

Then, the user must type an enter to submit the input, so the second `nextDouble()` can't find anything to read, since there is no number directly after the cursor. It needs a `nextLine()` to absorb the newline.

Unfortunately, you have a `nextLine()` in the wrong place, which absorbs the newline.

> num1 NEWLINE
>
> -*CURSOR HERE*- num2 NEWLINE
>
> operator NEWLINE

So, your program absorbs the double in the first `nextDouble()`, nothing in the second, and the newline in `nextLine()`.

To fix this, put a `scan.nextLine()` right after each `nextDouble()`. You don't have to read the `nextLine()` calls into anything, other than the one that has the operator.