# A case in my switch statement won't end

Tags: java, switch-statement

I just have to make a method that checks if three integers are the same, have the user tell an object to execute this method, and then ask the user for another command. When I put 'c' (it's ONLY this case that does this, I have another case that is logically identical), it will do what it's supposed to but then it will try to take the next input and run it through as a parameter to the method that has already been executed, from what I understand.

```
    something=in.nextLine();
    commands=something.charAt(0);
    do{
        switch(commands){
            //Blah blah blah other commands
            case 'c':
                boolean yes=object.allTheSame(in.nextInt(),in.nextInt(),in.nextInt());
                System.out.println(yes);
                System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");
                something=in.nextLine();
            break;
        }
        commands=something.charAt(0);
    }while(commands!='q');
```

Comment: You might be running into [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx). If that's the case, just put another `in.nextLine();` on its own line before `something=in.nextLine();`.

Answer (score 1):

The break you have in there [breaks the switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) and not the do-while loop.

(As your comparisons seem trivial, I think it's better form to use the tradition if-else.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's in the "Blah blah blah other commands" part, but if the first character of `something` is not `c`, then `commands` will apparently never change. You might want to do this:

```
something=in.nextLine();
int pos = 0;
commands=something.charAt(pos++);
do{
    switch(commands){
        //Blah blah blah other commands
        case 'c':
            boolean yes=object.allTheSame(in.nextInt(),in.nextInt(),in.nextInt());
            System.out.println(yes);
            System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");
            something=in.nextLine();
        break;
    }
    commands=something.charAt(pos++);
}while(commands!='q');
```