# Infinite Loop not working

Tags: java, infinite-loop

The code works the first time through. But after that, the output doesnt work.
The main goal of this is to create an infinite loop, of asking a user for a phrase, then a letter. Then, to output the number of occurences of the letter in the phrase.
Also - - how would i  go about breaking this loop by entering a word?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

for (;;) {

    System.out.println("Enter a word/phrase");
    String sentence = in.nextLine();

    int times = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter a character.");
    String letter = in.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        char lc = letter.charAt(0);
        char sc = sentence.charAt(i);
        if (lc == sc) {
            times++;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("The character appeared:" + times + " times.");
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. When you would want the loop to break?

Comment: while(true){
if (success) break;
}

Comment: the loop would break when the user enters "quit" as their phrase/word

Comment: Ah...mind reading has always been one of my worst skills.

Comment: If you want to use `nextLine` and `next` then you probably should read [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the for loop and replace it with a while.

The while loop should check for a phrase and it will drop out automatically when the phrase is met.

So something like

```
while (!phraseToCheckFor){
// your code
}
```

This sounds like homework so I won't post all the code but this should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an infinite loop, just do this:

```
for(;;) {  //or while(true) {
    //insert code here
}
```

You can break the loop by using the `break` statement, for example like this:

```
for(;;) {
    String s = in.nextLine();
    if(s.isEmpty()) {
        break; //loop terminates here
    }
    System.out.println(s + " isn't empty.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for your program to run correctly, you need to consume the last new line character. You can do this by adding a call to *nextLine*. 
Working example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (;;) {

            System.out.println("Enter a word/phrase");
            String sentence = in.nextLine();

            if (sentence.trim().equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }

            int times = 0;


            System.out.println("Enter a character.");
            String letter = in.next();

            for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
                char lc = letter.charAt(0);
                char sc = sentence.charAt(i);
                if (lc == sc) {
                    times++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The character appeared:" + times + " times.");
            in.nextLine();//consume the last new line
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't give OP ready code. Let him improve his programming abilities by showing his mistakes, not correcting them.