# Java Looping and input data

Tags: java, for-loop

When I was putting this code for input three name and mark. but the name doesn't looping 3 time just once I could input, directly the code jumped to input `mark1`. how can I check to input three name please!

```
public void in_array(String x[], float x2[], float x3[])
{
    for(i=0; i<x.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        x[i] = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter  Mark one:  ");
        x2[i] = in.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter  Mark two:  ");
        x3[i] = in.nextFloat();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
enter name:
Enter mark one:
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Thanks but it's not actual solution.

Comment: The solution is in the various answers. If you understand the problem, you can figure out the solution yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the nextFloat() method does not consume the newline character. You'll either have to consume that character manually after, or read a full line and parse your float manually.

A quick fix using solution #1 could look like this:

```
for(i=0; i<x.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    x[i] = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter  Mark one:  ");
    x2[i] = in.nextFloat();
    in.nextLine();   // consume newline character
    System.out.println("Enter  Mark two:  ");
    x3[i] = in.nextFloat();
    in.nextLine();   // consume newline character
}
```

Solution #2 would look like this:

```
for(i=0; i<x.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    x[i] = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter  Mark one:  ");
    x2[i] = Float.parseFloat(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter  Mark two:  ");
    x3[i] = Float.parseFloat(in.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: I like solution #2 it's great!