# Unable to print array 0th element

Tags: java, arrays

Sir i am trying to print array's 0th element but i can't.
Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prog3
{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = input.nextInt();
        String arr[] = new String[size];

        for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
            arr[i]= input.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.print(arr[0]);
    }
}
```

when i am trying to print `arr[0]` its return blank but when i print `arr[1]` it returns the 0th element value. would you please help me to find my error.

Comment: Sir i am new in java.Would you please explain the reason ?

Comment: see my edited answer for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this mate:

```
    input.nextLine();   // gobble the newline
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = input.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: the `nextLine()` method is a bit quirky, since there was a newline "hanging" after `nextInt()`. If you gobble it up, things should then work as you expect.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
arr[i]= input.nextLine();
```

to

```
arr[i]= input.next();
```

and it works. this is because `nextLine(`) reads a whitespace and then it looks like `arr[0]` is empty. You can see this, because if the `size` is 3 you can input only two times. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html for more information about scanner :)

Comment: Why does that work. Please explain your answer :)

Comment: Yes its working . Thank you so much .. would you please explain why nextLine() is not working

Comment: Are you sure he doesn't want to read lines containing ws? Since this would tokenize input with spaces, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Corrected code: Include `input.nextLine();`  after  `input.nextInt()`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prog3{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    String arr[] = new String[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    arr[i]= input.nextLine();
    }
         System.out.print(arr[0]);
  }

}
```

**Input** :

```
2
45
95
```

**Output**

```
45
```

**Explanation:**

The problem is with the **input.nextInt()** command it only reads the int value. So when you continue reading with **input.nextLine()** you receive the "\n" Enter key. So to skip this you have to add the **input.nextLine()**. [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)