# Using a scanner to read city names

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I'm trying to make a scanner read through a file. However, the problem is that the scanner keeps skipping the 0 position in the array. Below is the code and the output.

```
public void loadLocations(String fname) throws Exception {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fname));
        Locations = new String[in.nextInt()]; 
        in.reset();
        //writes lines to array.
        for (int i = 0; i < Locations.length; i++){     
            if (in.hasNextLine()){
                Locations[i] = in.nextLine();
            }

            else if (in.hasNext()) {
                Locations[i] = in.nextLine();

            }

        }   

        // close file
        in.close();
    }
```

This is the output

```
Loaded 4 cities: 
    has location id 0
    New York has location id -1
    Los Angeles has location id 2
    Chicago has location id -1
```

Comment: I would recommend you to follow Java naming conventions. `Locations`, since it's a variable, should be named `locations`.

Comment: Try writing a uni test or use an IDE to debug

Comment: Can you share the file with us? May be a few records.

Comment: the cities text file or the actual program text file

Comment: That was it Thanks I have been messing with this for like 3 hours lol

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in.nextInt() does not automatically go to the next line.  So you are reading the rest of that first line as blank.

Try replacing in.reset() with in.nextLine()