# How to add arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods, calculator

I am very new to programming and I have a problem that I just cannot figure out. Last week I made a menu calculator that called methods to perform arithmetic on double values or to pick a random number. This week I need to change that it so that instead of double values, it performs arithmetic on arrays. Here is an example of what it is supposed to do.

```
Menu 
1. Add 
2. Subtract 
3. Multiply 
4. Divide 5. Dot product 
6. Generate random array 
7. Quit 

What would you like to do? 1 
How many values are in the arrays? 3 
Enter the values in the first array, separated by spaces: 
2 4 6 
Enter the values in the second array, separated by spaces: 
1 3 5 
The result is [3.0, 7.0, 11.0]
```

This doesn't look like it should be very complicated but I keep getting errors, and when I try to fix them I just get more errors. Things are spiraling out of control and I just have a mess on my hands now, so I think I need to start over. This is what the code for my method calculator looks like. If anyone could give me some hint as to where to begin, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you very much if you decide to take the time to read through this mess.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class methodCalculator{

    public static int getMenuOption(){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int invalid=0;
        while (invalid<3){
            System.out.println("MENU");
            System.out.println("1. +");
            System.out.println("2. -");
            System.out.println("3. *");
            System.out.println("4. /");
            System.out.println("5. Generate a random number.");
            System.out.println("6. Quit");

            System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
            int menuSelect = input.nextInt();
            //Selects an item from the menu

            if (menuSelect==1||menuSelect==2||menuSelect==3||menuSelect==4||menuSelect==5||menuSelect==6){
                return(menuSelect);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Sorry, "+menuSelect+" is not an option.");
                invalid++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Too many invalid inputs. Try again later");
        System.exit(0);
        return(0);
    }

    public static double getOperand(String prompt){
        System.out.println(prompt);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        return(input.nextDouble());
    }

    public static double addition(double one,double two){
        return(one+two);
    }

    public static double subtraction(double one,double two){
        return(one-two);
    }

    public static double multiplication(double one, double two){
        return(one*two);
    }

    public static double division(double one, double two){
        if(two != 0){
            return(one/two);
        }
        else {
            return(Double.NaN);
        }
    }

    public static double random(double upper,double lower){
        double upperLimit = getOperand("Enter upper limit.");
        double lowerLimit = getOperand("Enter lower limit.");
        double randomVal = (lowerLimit + (int)(Math.random() * ((upperLimit - lowerLimit)+1)));
        return(randomVal);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double numONE = 0.0;
        double numTWO = 0.0;
        double upperLimit = 0.0;
        double lowerLimit = 0.0;

        int menuOption = getMenuOption();
        while(menuOption == 1 || menuOption == 2 || menuOption == 3 || menuOption == 4||menuOption==5||menuOption==6){
            if(menuOption == 1 || menuOption == 2 || menuOption == 3 || menuOption == 4){
                numONE=getOperand("Enter the first number.");
                //Stores input as numONE
                numTWO=getOperand("Enter the second number.");
                //Stores input as numTWO
            }
            if(menuOption == 1){
                double sum= addition(numONE,numTWO);
                System.out.println(sum);
                //Adds two numbers
                menuOption=getMenuOption();
            }
            else if(menuOption == 2){
                double difference=subtraction(numONE,numTWO);
                System.out.println(difference);
                //Subtracts second number from first number
                menuOption=getMenuOption();
            }
            else if(menuOption == 3){
                double product=multiplication(numONE,numTWO);
                System.out.println(product);
                //Multiplies two numbers
                menuOption=getMenuOption();
            }
            else if(menuOption == 4){
                double quotient=division(numONE,numTWO);
                System.out.println(quotient);
                menuOption=getMenuOption();
            }
            else if(menuOption == 5){
                double randomVal=random(numONE,numTWO);
                System.out.println(randomVal);
                //Displays a random integer between an upper and a lower limit
                menuOption=getMenuOption();
            }
            else if(menuOption==6){
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which errors are you getting ?

Comment: Why are you printing "1. +" instead of "1. Add"?

Comment: Looks like you are having troubles with the arrays. Can you show what you have done so far? If not, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html would be a good place to start.

Comment: I don't see any array in your code except `String[] args` in main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will gave you an example for the addition. Change you addition function to:

```
public static double[] addition(double[] one,double[] two){
    double[] resultset = new double[one.length];  //creat new array for the results
    for(int i = 0; i<one.length; i++)             //iterate over the arrays to calculate the results
        resultset[i] = one[i] + two[i];           //calculate the result
    return resultset;                             //return resultset array
}
```

In main replace the two doubles with two arrays and creat a size variable:

```
    double[] array1 = null;
    double[] array2 = null;
    double upperLimit = 0.0;
    double lowerLimit = 0.0;
    int arraysize = 0;
```

in main where you read the two ints, make for-loops to read the two arrays:

```
        if(menuOption == 1 || menuOption == 2 || menuOption == 3 || menuOption == 4){
            //arraysize
            System.out.println("How many values are in the arrays?");
            arraysize = input.nextInt();
            //1st array
            array1 = new double[arraysize];
            System.out.println("Enter the values in the first array, separated by spaces: ");
            input.nextLine();       //consume whitespaces
            String number = input.nextLine();
            for(int i = 0; i<arraysize; i++)
                array1[i] = Integer.parseInt(number.split(" ")[i]);  //split the string at the whitespaces and convert it to an int
            //2nd array
            array2 = new double[arraysize];
            System.out.println("Enter the values in the secound array, separated by spaces: ");
            number = input.nextLine();
            for(int i = 0; i<arraysize; i++)
                array2[i] = Integer.parseInt(number.split(" ")[i]);
        }
```

and the last step is printing out the result:

```
        if(menuOption == 1){
            double[] results = addition(array1,array2);
            for(int i = 0; i<arraysize; i++)
                System.out.print(results[i]+" ");
            menuOption=getMenuOption();
        }
```

Example Input:

```
MENU
1. +
2. -
3. *
4. /
5. Generate a random number.
6. Quit
What would you like to do?
1
How many values are in the arrays?
3
Enter the values in the first array, separated by spaces: 
1 2 3
Enter the values in the secound array, separated by spaces: 
4 5 6
```

Output:

```
5.0 7.0 9.0
```

Now its your turn. You only have to creat the other calculation functions and the input will be parsed to an int atm. change it to double.

Comment: Thank you for the point in the right direction. This helped a lot and it turned out great. Much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, the only thing I don't understand is why this line was necessary:

Comment: input.nextLine();       //consume whitespaces
I realize it won't work without it, but I do not fully understand why.

Comment: its because the input.nextInt(); it only reads the int value. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx