# Java Take String input from console

Tags: java

I was trying to take string input in java. My input should be like this

```
3
1,1,bugs@bunny.com,123 Sesame St.,New York,NY,10011,12345689010
1,2,bugs@bunny.com,123 Sesame St.,New York,NY,10011,12345689010
1,3,bugs@bunny.com,123 Sesame St.,New York,NY,10011,12345689010
```

So, I tried this

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int TotalNumber = in.nextInt();
        String[] Data = new String[TotalNumber];
        for (int Counter = 0; Counter < TotalNumber; Counter++) {

            Data[Counter] = in.next();

        }

        in.close();

        for (int counter = 0; counter < Data.length; counter++) {


            System.out.println(Data[counter]);

        }
```

My output is showing this

```
1,1,bugs@bunny.com,123
Sesame
St.,New
```

What is my problem ? How take input string line properly ?

**Update**

I found my solution at here [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Answer (score 1):

`next()` breaks at a whitespace. Instead, you should use `nextLine()` to input the entire line to your string:

```
int TotalNumber = in.nextInt();
String[] Data = new String[TotalNumber];
for (int Counter = 0; Counter < TotalNumber; Counter++) {
    Data[Counter] = in.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: I tried with nextLine() 3
1,1,bugs@bunny.com,123 Sesame St.,New York,NY,10011,12345689010
1,1,bugs@bunny.com,123 Sesame St.,New York,NY,10011,12345689010 it only take 2 inputs from me

Comment: could you explain what happened? I mean the output.

Comment: First I gave 3(It should take 3 lines of string right ?) then hit entered first line then again hit enter and the second line then I hit enter and only two lines are showing. But, It should be take 3 lines and show 3 lines

Comment: I think an enter was pressed accidentally? Are you seeing the same output always.

Answer (score 0):

Try with  `Data[Counter] = in.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char[] sArray;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a Palindrome : ");
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

        sArray = new char[s.length()];

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            sArray[i] = s.charAt(i);
            System.out.print(sArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Mureinik modified code)..

```
int TotalNumber = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
String[] Data = new String[TotalNumber];
for (int Counter = 0; Counter < TotalNumber; Counter++) {
    Data[Counter] = in.nextLine();
}
```

You need a `nextLine()` after taking the `int` because you will press enter after taking `int` and that enter is read by `nextLine()` in the `Data[0]`.