# string input with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProgramAssignment1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reader();
    }

    public static void reader() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the Number of Students you would like to input for");
        int count = input.nextInt();
        int[] scores = new int[count];
        String[] name = new String[count];
        for (int i = 1; i <= count;i++) {
             System.out.println("Please input the students names ");
            name[i] = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What is there score?");
            scores[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
            System.out.print(name[a]);
            System.out.print(" "+scores[a]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

so basically i need user input to an array but it keeps giving me the same error

Example run:

```
Please enter the Number of Students you would like to input for
2
Please input the students names 
What is there score?
5
Please input the students names 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at ProgramAssignment1.reader(ProgramAssignment1.java:18)
    at ProgramAssignment1.main(ProgramAssignment1.java:7)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Comment: Arrays are 0 base indexed. I.e, indices start from 0 to array.length -1 . Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: ok it doesnt let me input the string now

Comment: Use `input.nextLine()` after `input.nextInt()` to consume the '\n'. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx

Answer (score 2):

In Java, indexes of an array go from `0` through `length - 1`, not `1` through `length`.  Arrays are 0-based.  You're looping one too high, and you're running off the end of your array.

Change

```
for (int i = 1; i <= count;i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < count;i++) {
```

You'll need to change your `a` `for` loop similarly (stop when `count` is reached, not `10`).

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You are iterating for loop to 10.

`for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)`

Suppose the count is less than 10. What will happen? `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

**2.** Change

```
`for (int i = 1; i <= count;i++)`
```

in to

```
for (int i = 0; i < count;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the index starts from 0 not 1.
Change:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= count;i++) {
    System.out.println("Please input the students names ");
    name[i] = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is there score?");
    scores[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

To:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= count;i++) {
    System.out.println("Please input the students names ");
    name[i] = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is there score?");
    scores[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays start at index 0. Try to iterate in for bucles starting with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java, like most programming langages `Arrays` are addressed with an `offset`.

That means `name[1]` point to the object 1 past the begining of the name array, becuase the offset is one.

conversely the first element of an array would be `0 past that start of the array` or `name[0]` and the last element will be `the length of the array minus one past the begining of the array` or `name[ name.length - 1 ]`

In your code `for (int i = 1; i <= count;i++) {` goes through the offsets `1,2,3,4,5`, but 5 is 5 past the begining of the array, or the sixth element of a 5 element array.

Adjust you code so the loop uses the offsets `0,1,2,3,4` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

ZouZou is right.  Arrays are 0 based, you are going to want to run your loops from 0 to array.length-1.

For example if I have:

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++ {
    System.out.println(array[i] + " ") 
}
```

I will get:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

If my for loop was from i=1; i<=array.length; i++, I would get:
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 [OUT OF BOUNDS]