# Scanner.nextLine() console input problems

Tags: java, input, console-application

I have trouble using the nextLine() method from the java Scanner class.

I need to read a whole line from the console, with spaces, and I cannot do that because the previous reading of an int/string is somehow affecting the reading of the line and I get an empty string.

I can read just one string with next() but I need the spaces between...

here is a chunk of the code:

```
        String[] parametri = new String[7];

        System.out.println("Izberite vrsto transakcije:\n 1.Dobavnica \n 2.Izdajnica\n");
        parametri[0] = String.valueOf(scan.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Korisnik (id): ");
        parametri[2] = String.valueOf(scan.nextInt());
        //!!! here is the error
        System.out.print("Korisnik (ime): ");
        parametri[3] = scan.nextLine();
        //!!! and here
        System.out.print("Artikel: ");
        parametri[4] = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enota količine: ");
        parametri[5] = scan.next();

        System.out.print("Količina: ");
        parametri[6] = String.valueOf(scan.nextInt());
```

The output is in slovenian, it's a transaction parameters input

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After call to `nextInt()` there is still a caret return character ('\n') in input buffer. You need to remove it using `scanner.skip("[\r\n]+")`

Comment: with this I have an infinite input

Comment: @Mark: at which point in the program do you insert the skip statement?

Comment: after:  parametri[2] = String.valueOf(scan.nextInt());

Comment: @Mark: hmm, works for me. Are you on windows? try `scanner.skip("[\r\n]")`

Comment: yes, windows and with eclipse IDE and with `"[\r\n]"` it's the same as it is without anything

Comment: @Mark: mm, `[\r\n]+` then?