# Scanner stops to read input

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean US1 = false;
    boolean game;
    int score = 1;
    int wage = 0;   
    int fin_score = 0;
    String ans;

    if (US1 == false)
    {
        game = false;
        System.out.println (score);
        System.out.println("Enter a wager");
        wage =  input.nextInt();
    }

    if (wage < score)
    {
        System.out.println ("What is the capital of Liberia?");
        ans = input.nextLine();

        if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Monrovia"))
        {
            System.out.println ("You got it right!");
            System.out.println ("Final score " + fin_score);
        }
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

For some reason once I enter a value for wage, the code prints "What is the capital of Liberia?" then terminates. Im not sure what is going on, why the scanner will not let me input the answer for the question

Comment: `Scanner`? I don't see a `Scanner` in the code you provided.

Comment: Where is `input` declared?

Comment: [This is a known problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Comment: Also, how do I check that the input for the wage is indeed an integer, and not anything else? (ie the user cannot enter  a letter, decimal, ect.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Scanner `nextInt` doesn't consume the <kbd>Enter</kbd>

So you must use a `nextLine()` for it

Add the following:

`input.nextLine();`

right after

`wage =  input.nextInt();`