# java using nextLine() in for loop ,

Tags: java

Instead of printing out each statement and waiting for input  it prints out both statements and waits for one input.

```
for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
{
    System.out.println("course: ");
    courses[i] = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("teacher: ");
    teachers[i] = sc.nextLine();
}
```

Output:

> Enter number of classes:   2    course:
>
> teacher:

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new line` has been consumed be `courses[i] = sc.nextLine();` so that is why it skipped

**solution:**

add `nextLine` before the forLoop:

```
sc.nextLine(); //will consume the new line
for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
```

Comment: thank you very much it works, so if i understood correctly the new line that is caused by println() is what is being consumed.

Comment: @user3786610 no it is the nextInt(). because when you input 2 it will just consumed the 2 not the newLine after it.

Comment: yes that makes more since ty,