# Prompt for input using do and switch

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    char OperatorCode;
    int answer;
    int firstOperand;
    int secondOperand;
    String inputString;
    boolean quit = false;
    Scanner inLine = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
        System.out.print("Enter the Operator Code (A,S,M or D): ");
        inputString = inLine.nextLine();
        OperatorCode = inputString.charAt(0);
        if (OperatorCode != 'Q'){
            inputString = inputString.substring(1, inputString.length());
            Scanner string = new Scanner(inputString);
            System.out.print("Enter the First Operand: ");
            firstOperand = string.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter the Second Operand: ");
            secondOperand = string.nextInt();
            switch (OperatorCode){
                case 'A' : answer = (firstOperand + secondOperand);
                           System.out.println(firstOperand + " + " + secondOperand + " is " + answer);
                case 'S' : answer = (firstOperand - secondOperand);
                           System.out.println(firstOperand + " - " + secondOperand + " is " + answer);
                case 'M' : answer = (firstOperand * secondOperand);
                           System.out.println(firstOperand + " * " + secondOperand + " is " + answer);
                case 'D' : answer = (firstOperand / secondOperand);
                           System.out.println(firstOperand + " / " + secondOperand + " is " + answer);
                           break;
            }               
        } else 
              quit = true;
    }while (!quit);
} 
}
```

What seems to be the problem on my code? It outputs the first statement(?) fine and I can input my desired character there but when it goes to the second statement(?) ("Enter the first Operand.") I get an error which says"

"Enter the First Operand: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException"

Can somebody please point out my fault?

Comment: Add `string.nextLine();` after `System.out.print("Enter the Second Operand: ");`.

Comment: The lack of `break` statements at the end of each `case` is at least one problem...

Comment: Thank you Jon and hagubear:) I didn't see those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `string.nextLine();`  instead of `.nextInt();` method as it doesnt takes care of EOL while nextLine parses it

And why do you pass the `string` as the parameter to the scanner class here ,

```
Scanner string = new Scanner(inputString);
```

i guess it could be , `(System.in)`

Also add `break;` to your case A,S and M as John suggested

Comment: Thank you but I still get the same error and now it added that string cannot be converted to int.

Comment: Oh wow. How could I have overlooked that. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: break; and System.in . Tho it did not need to be string.nextLine();

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem of remaining '\n'. Maybe this question may help you : [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Comment: I'm afraid that that is not the problem :/ I'm still getting the error.