# IndexOutOfBoundsException when taking character input from the user

Tags: java, exception, charat

In the 15th line `ch = s1.charAt(0);`,
 why ch is not getting the 0th word of s1, i.e., the operator .

I've tried without using the try-catch method but then the error was regarding the exception

and now no exception, no errors but the program don't ask for operator and directly after inputting 
the 1st and 2nd value , it shows the exception"can't do that"

please post your kind replies, thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class apples {
    public static void calcu() {
        try{
            int a, b;
            String s1;
            char ch;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the 1st value : ");
            a = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter the 2nd value : ");
            b = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter the operator : ");
            s1 = sc.nextLine();
            ch = s1.charAt(0);
            System.out.println("yo");

                switch(ch){
                case '+' : System.out.print("sum is " + (a+b));
                case '-' : System.out.print("Substraction is : " +(a-b));
                case '*' : System.out.print("Multiplication is : " + (a*b));
                case '/' : System.out.print("Multiplication is : " + (a/b));
                default  : System.out.print("wtf yo");
                }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("cant do that ");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        apples obj = new apples();
        obj.calcu();
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't know what your input is, or your expected output. The fact that you're not bothering to log what the exception *is* doesn't help, either... please include the exception details in your logging (e.g. `System.out.println("Error: " + e);`)

Comment: Im just making normal calculator sir,
and was learning about how to input the character variable

Comment: That doesn't help us diagnose the problem though - it doesn't tell us what you entered, or anything about the exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Comment: hmm... thanks sir
can u tell me please , that the parseInt method fall under which category and where could i learn it ?

Answer (score 3):

You should replace `nextInt` with `nextLine` :

```
        System.out.print("Enter the 1st value : ");
        a = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter the 2nd value : ");
        b = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter the operator : ");
        s1 = sc.nextLine();
        ch = s1.charAt(0);
```

When `s1 = sc.nextLine();` follows `b = sc.nextInt()`, it returns an empty String, since it returns the end of the line that contained that int. When you try to get the first character of an empty String, you get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: btw this parseInt method fall under which category sir ?

Comment: @TakatSingh What do you mean by "fall under which category"? It's a static method of the Integer class.