# StringIndexOutOFBoundsException: 0

Tags: java

I am a relative beginner to Java and am having an issue with a user controlled do-while loop that accepts user input to repeat. Here is the code at the end of the loop.

```
System.out.print("Do you wish to continue? (Y for yes " +
                            "/ N for no)");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        input.length();
        repeat = input.charAt(0);

        }while (repeat == 'Y' | repeat == 'y');
```

I know it's throwing the exception because of the value, but can't figure out what to do to fix it, as I'm sure it's relatively simple. Thanks for the help.

Edit 1:
Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
String index out of range: 0 
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source) 
at FractionTest.main(FractionTest.java:59)
```

Comment: Looks like you read empty line.

Comment: Sorry I left the stacktrace out. Here it is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at FractionTest.main(FractionTest.java:59)

Comment: possible duplicate of [IndexOutOfBoundsException when taking character input from the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619851/indexoutofboundsexception-when-taking-character-input-from-the-user)

Comment: Post stacktrace inside question. It is unreadable as comment. To do so use [edit] option.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you read empty line which returned you empty string `""` so there is no characters there (not even 0th).

It usually happens when you are using `nextLine` right after other `nextABC` methods like `nextInt` since such methods doesn't consume line separators, and `nextLine` reads text until next line separator (or end of stream).

In that case you can add `nextLine` after that `nextInt` to consume line separator.

Anyway to avoid reading character from empty string and exception you can use something like

```
} while (input.toLowerCase().startsWith("y"));
```

instead of

```
    input.length();//this actually doesn't change anything, you can remove it
    repeat = input.charAt(0);

} while (repeat == 'Y' | repeat == 'y');
```

Comment: I added the above if statement and it's still throwing the same exception.

Comment: @Steve I updated my answer to add alternative way of skipping this error, and probable cause of getting empty string.

Answer (score 1):

As @Phesmo mentioned you may be getting a 0-length line. This is an obscure problem. Have you called `nextInt()`, `nextLong()`, `nextShort()`, `nextByte()`,  or `nextBoolean()` on the Scanner before calling `nextLine()`?

---

Try this

```
System.out.print("Do you wish to continue? (Y for yes / N for no)");

char ans;
do {
   ans = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
   // filter input
} while (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y' || ans == 'N' || ans == 'n');

repeat = ans;

} while (repeat == 'Y' | repeat == 'y');
```

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()):

> `String Scanner#next()`
>   Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

Or this

```
System.out.print("Do you wish to continue? (Y for yes / N for no)");    
repeat = keyboard.next("[YyNn]").charAt(0);

} while (repeat == 'Y' | repeat == 'y');
```

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.lang.String)):

> `String Scanner#next(String pattern)`
>   Returns the next token if it matches the pattern constructed from the specified string.

`"[YyNn]"` is a character class pattern, it means *match any character from the set*.

Comment: ++ for idea of using `next` instead of `nextLine` (but you could add more info about why you wanted to use it here)

Comment: This fixed the exception issue. Thanks naXa. I have never seen that format for an input argument to cover all the possible inputs.

Comment: @Steve, it's an advanced topic. If you want to know more, read about regular expressions.