# ArrayList get() method not returning first index value

Tags: java, arraylist

I created an arrayList to store String values.When i am going to fetch values from my arrayList it doesn't return me the first value of it;s 0th index.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
int noInput=scan.nextInt();

for(int i=0; i < noInput/2; i++)
   arrayList.add(scan.nextLine());       

for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
   System.out.println("ArrayList:"+arrayList.get(i) + " "  + i );
```

Comment: The problem is much more likely that you didn't add to the ArrayList what you thought you added. Focus your debug efforts on what is going into the ArrayList.

Comment: Yeah, i can understand that thing.but still i am not able to identify the problem.can u help me figuring this problem

Comment: Can you show the error of your code . . .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Answer (score 2):

Use `scan.next()` instead of `scan.nextLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because [`Scanner#nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) reads *only* the `int` value, then `nextLine` in the first iteration will consume the remaining `\n` (the enter you hit after you entered the integer value).

To fix this, add `nextLine` after `nextInt` or use `next` instead of `nextInt`.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because your list is never filled. I think the first loop isn't gone into, so nothing is added to the array. 
    `for(int i=0; i < noInput/2; i++)
            arrayList.add(scan.nextLine());`

Try debugging it or printing the size of the arraylist