# Program doesn't prompt for string input but does for other data types

Tags: java, input

In this program i needed the user to input yes / no to be set in another array class. But the string input doesnt work. I tried it with an integer and it worked but not with a string.

package airliner.boarding.system;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BoardPlane {

```
private boolean firstClass[];
private boolean economyClass[];
private static Scanner input ; 


public BoardPlane(){
    firstClass = new boolean[5];
    economyClass = new boolean[5];
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
}

public void setSeat(int seatClass){
    if(seatClass == 1){
        fillFirstClass();
    }else if(seatClass == 2){
        fillEconomyClass();
    }
}

private void fillEconomyClass(){
    for(int counter = 0; counter < economyClass.length; counter++){
        if(economyClass[counter] == false){
            economyClass[counter] = true;
            System.out.println("Your seat number is "+(++counter)+" in the economy class");
            break;
        }else if(counter == 4){
            System.out.println("Economy class is filled. is it okay to place you in first class? YES/NO: ");
            String choice = input.nextLine();
            choice = choice.toUpperCase();
            if(choice.equals("YES")){
                 switchSeats(2);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Next flight leaves in three hours.");
            }
        }
    }
}

private void fillFirstClass(){
    for(int counter = 0; counter < firstClass.length; counter++){
        if(firstClass[counter] == false){
            firstClass[counter] = true;
            System.out.println("Your seat number is "+(++counter)+" in the first class");
            break;
        }else if(counter == 4 ){
            System.out.println("First class is filled. is it okay to place you in economy class? YES/NO:");
            String choice = input.nextLine();
            choice = choice.toUpperCase();
            if(choice.equals("YES")){
                 switchSeats(1);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Next flight leaves in three hours.");
            }

        }
    }
}

private void switchSeats(int i){
    if(i == 1){
        for(int counter = 0; counter < economyClass.length; counter++){
            if(economyClass[counter] == false){
                economyClass[counter] = true;
                System.out.println("Your seat number is "+(++counter)+" in the economy class");
                break;
            }else if(counter == 4){
                System.out.println("Economy class is filled");
            }
        }
    }else if(i == 2){
        for(int counter = 0; counter < firstClass.length; counter++){
            if(firstClass[counter] == false){
                firstClass[counter] = true;
                System.out.println("Your seat number is "+(++counter)+" in the first class");
                break;
            }else if(counter == 4){
                System.out.println("First class is filled");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    BoardPlane plane = new BoardPlane();
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for first class and 2 for economy class: ");
        int userInput = input.nextInt();
        plane.setSeat(userInput);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what doesn't work ? have you tried next instead of nextLine ?
maybe print the value of choice right after reading it, maybe you have something different

Comment: Also... please tell which line numbers are you talking about. This class takes input at multiple places.

Comment: I agree with Sarvesh: put all the repeating code in seperate methods you reuse. it'll make debugging/correcting a lot easier.

Comment: System.out.println("Economy class is filled. is it okay to place you in first class? YES/NO: ");
            String choice = input.nextLine();
            choice = choice.toUpperCase();
            if(choice.equals("YES")){
                 switchSeats(2);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Next flight leaves in three hours.");

Comment: Please don't post code into comments; it's unreadable there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `nextInt()` it only reads the number, not the rest of the line and not the new line you typed.

This means if you later call `nextLine()` it will read what ever was after the number i.e. most likely nothing.

A simple work around is to ignore the rest of the line after the number.

```
int userInput = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); // ignore the rest of the line.
```

Comment: I do not want to accept an integer input, I need a String. Which the program doesn't prompt to accept when you run the program.

Comment: @ahmedOnawale before you ask for a String you ask for a number.  When you read the number you don't read the newline after it, but when you later ask for a line you expect it to wait for YES/NO but instead it is still reading the line after the number.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem, when you use scanner, and put the message with System.out.println(), newLine not work correctly.I dont know why ?! when you make input = new Scanner(System.in) after out your message in console, it's work correct.

but u can make a method for give user input and in this method make a feresh scanner like this :

publis static String getUserInput(String message){

System.out.println(message);

input = new Scanner(System.in);

return input.nextLine();

}