# for loop breaking early

Tags: java, loops

I have a for loop that is entered if the user chooses so.

```
System.out.println("Single Player=1\t Two Player=2\t Report Single  
Tables=3\t Report all tables=4\t Exit=5");
choice= sc.nextInt();


if(choice ==1){
    for (int i = 0; i <= np.length; i++) {
        if (np[i] == 0) {
            np[i]++;
            System.out.print("Enter name:");
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            player1[i] = str;
            break;

    }
}}
```

When i enter the for loop, the enter name prompt pops up as well as the menu again, which is supposed to appear after the loop finishes. What i am confused about is why it is breaking before i can even enter the name.

Comment: Your bracketing isn't correct.  Can you please close them properly?  I assume you are missing 2 of them at the end, to close the for basic block and the if basic block.

Comment: What is `sc`? Also you most likely don't want `i <= np.length`.

Comment: `String str = sc.nextLine(); player1[i] = str;` could be replaced with: `player1[i] = sc.nextLine();` and what is `np` ? how can we help you without knowing what it contains ?

Comment: really think about what `i = 0 && i <= np.length` means when both `i == 0` and `np.length() == 0`

Comment: @irradiatedcat - read for comprehension, I did not ask what it was for, I asked what do you think the logic is when the array is empty and `i == 0`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Answer (score 2):

### Show all the code

Otherwise everyone is just guessing.

### Learn to use a step debugger

look at what `np.length` equals when `i == 0` and then you will most likely have your answer.

#### Spelling it out

first pass through the look `i == 0` and most likely `np.length == 0` as well but we have absolutely no idea because you did not post all the relevant code.

What would `i == 0 && i <= np.length` be when the array is 0 length?

```
for (i = 0; i <= 0; i++) 
{ 
  /* how many times do you think this will loop? */ 
}
```

Comment: I'm debating with myself wether I should upvote or flag as "not an answer". Decided to upvote because it *is* useful (though it's not an answer) :)

Comment: how very romantic of you, is it because Valentine is coming? :P

Answer (score 0):

You should add `sc.nextLine();` right after `choice= sc.nextInt();`. It'll solve your problem.

Because when you enter the number for `choice`, you press `Enter`. Number is read to `choice` by `sc.nextInt()` but your `Enter` still in input stream. 
Then, `String str = sc.nextLine();` read your `Enter` and break your loop instead of waiting you to Enter a name.

```
System.out.println("Single Player=1\t Two Player=2\t Report Single  
Tables=3\t Report all tables=4\t Exit=5");
choice= sc.nextInt();

sc.nextLine(); //this line will consume your Enter (end line) char

if(choice ==1){
    for (int i = 0; i <= np.length; i++) {
        if (np[i] == 0) {
             np[i]++;
             System.out.print("Enter name:");
             String str = sc.nextLine();
             player1[i] = str;
             break;
          }
     }
}
```