# ArrayList Scanner input help Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to write a code where you sort a given list of numbers, and I'm trying to do so using ArrayList. I am using a while loop to allow for repeated inputs. This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class sortinggg {

    public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        int count= 0;

        System.out.println("Enter your numbers.");

        while (keyboard.hasNextInt()); {
            number.add(keyboard.nextInt()); 
        }
```

The integer count is irrelevant right now, as I only use it when I am sorting the list.

The problem is that after I input my numbers, even if I type in a string (for example), the program doesn't move on to the next line of code. Am i missing anything here?

P.S. I tired looking up questions that have been asked previously on this topic, but none of the solutions suggested worked for me.Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: `while (keyboard.hasNextInt()); {` Remove the semicolon. That ends your loop body. The `number.add(keyboard.nextInt());` is in a different (non-loop) block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Well spotted!

Comment: @ElliottFtisch That fixed it! Thank you for your help, new to Java and coding in general..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        System.out.println("Enter your numbers:");

        while (keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
            number.add(keyboard.nextInt()); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Modifications:**

1. In `while (keyboard.hasNextInt());` remove `semicolon(;)` at the end.

Here `while loop` will keep adding values to the `arraylist` until you provide int values.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place the `;` just after the `while` is wrong. It does not let you to execute the body. Then how are you going to skip the loop. You may ask the end user to enter some special value and use it to break the loop. The corrected version is given below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter your numbers or -1 to skip.");

        while (keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
            int num = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (num == -1) {
                break;
            }
            number.add(num);

        }

        System.out.println(number);

    }
```