# Using the Scanner function to get user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

so I am trying to use the scanner class to receive a few different inputs from a user. They can enter in a movie title, year, director, duration, actors, and genre.

However, for one of the user inputs, it is printing the director and duration together.

Here is a screenshot for more reference. Why is is asking for user input for director and duration at the same time but expecting a user input for duration?

[Code and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrqMd.png)

```
    System.out.println("Enter the title: ");
    String title = myObj.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the year: ");
    int year = myObj.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the duration: ");
    int duration = myObj.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the director: ");
    String director = myObj.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the actors: ");
    String actors  = myObj.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Enter the genre: ");
    String genre = myObj.nextLine();
    int rating = ran.nextInt(10) + 1;
```

Comment: Did you make an effort to search the problem before?

Comment: Add code as text not as image.

Comment: Avoid using images as a replacement of pasting the source code.

Comment: Sure, let me edit it.

Comment: just added the code @steven7mwesigwa

Comment: Yes, however, I believe the reason I didn't find it is because I wasn't wording my problem correctly. @AKSingh

Comment: Add myObj.nextLine() after nextInt(). Otherwise, the new line input you entered by hitting enter will not get read/consumed.

Comment: @Aman [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo?rq=1) is a useful link.

Comment: Kindly check out [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `nextInt()` will not consume the newline. It will instead be consumed by the subsequent call to `nextLine()` when getting the director. To solve this you can instead call `nextLine()` and then `Integer.parseInt()` to convert the string to an integer.

Comment: Oh ok, so what I think you are saying is that the nextInt() does not take the entire new line. Therefore, the remaining blank space, for the nextLine() is consumed by the following call. That is terrible wording on my behalf.

Answer (score 0):

***`.nextInt()`*** will only read the integer provided in the input. Now the scanner cursor is at **"/n"**(newline). To avoid this you can either use

> int duration = Integer.parseInt(myObj.nextLine());

or

`int duration = myObj.nextInt();`
`myObj.nextLine();`